# Complex reduceByKey operation in Spark to compute multiple aggr. fields + count dist

Tags: count, apache-spark, reduce

I have this RDD (id, (a, b, c)), where c is a string that can be repeated for different id. Also id can be repeated.
Now, I need to aggregate by id, and the aggregation will be"
sum(a),
sum(b)
count distinct (c).

I was thinking of using reduceByKey, which I know how to use for the sum part, but no idea how to do for the count distinct

Ideally, I was thinking of something like:

```
RDD.reduceByKey((x,y)=> (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2, countDistinct(x._3, y._3)))
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

*** UPDATE (1) ***
Best I could do at the moment is:

```
RDD.reduceByKey((x,y)=> (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2, (x._3 + "," + y._3))).map(row => row._1, row._2._1, row._2._2, row._2._3.split(",").distinct.length
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of right now is to use an intermediate set, and check it's size after. I'll think if there's a way to do this in one method

```
RDD.aggregateByKey((0,0,Set[Int]()))(
  (x,y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2, x._3 + y._3),
  (x,y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2, x._3 ++ y._3)
).mapValues(x => (x._1, x._2, x._3.size))
```